# Get multiple lines into a single stream

Tags: ibm-midrange

I work on AS400 and have a very large file which I download in .txt using IMAIL.
I need to send this file in a single stream. I get the .txt file having the data
broken up into multiple lines and lots of spaces at the end of each line.
The data which I have in the .txt file doesnt follow any pattern.

How do I get the data in a single stream?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Sohail

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you mean by getting "the data in a single stream"?  Can you provide examples of the data you download and the data you expect?  This question may be more appropriate for [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: It sounds like IMAIL puts documents into the DB2 file system as opposed to the IFS.  Contact InFORM and find out if they support the IFS.

Answer (score 0):

> I get the .txt file having the data broken up into multiple lines and
>   lots of spaces at the end of each line.

To me, it sounds like a program-described or source file member copied to the directory with CPYTOSTMF. The initial fixed-length records are preserving trailing spaces and some combination of newline and carriage return characters is added at the end of each line. That would cause both the excess spaces and the "multiple lines".

It would possibly be best to run your own CPYTOSTMF command to generate the IFS streamfile requesting perhaps only *LF as the record delimiter. Then, after the streamfile is in the target directory, you could run the Qshell tr utility to remove the line-ending newline:

```
tr -d '\n' < mystmf.txt > NOLF.txt
```

The output from tr would be NOLF.txt in that example.